# Torrent with GUI for Gnome on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, gnome, bittorrent

I'm running Gnome Desktop on CentOS, I was wondering if anyone knows of a good Torrent program like uTorrent that will run on Gnome CentOS?

If so does anyone have a tutorial on how to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install **deluge** this way:

1.Create the repository config file /etc/yum.repos.d/linuxtech.repo:

```
[linuxtech]
name=LinuxTECH
baseurl=http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/RPM-GPG-KEY-LinuxTECH.NET
```

2.Install deluge rpm package:

```
 # yum install deluge
```

---

original link:

http://pkgs.org/centos-6/linuxtech/deluge-1.3.5-1.el6.noarch.rpm.html

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try using [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/). You can run it as a daemon process and then connect to it using a web browser on port :9001. This is what I do so that multiple users can connect to the same instance and manage the single instance.

*screenshot of web client - click image for larger view*

[image: ss of web client]

You can also use a dedicated fat client version that will connect to the remote daemon so that you can manage it.

*screenshot of fat client - click image for larger view*

[image: ss of fat client]

Answer (score 3):

`Tixati` is a good torrent downloader client. You can get it [here](http://www.tixati.com/download/linux.html)

RPMS are available and you can install these with `rpm -ivh <rpm>` command.

Answer (score 0):

**deluge** (python) - wrote on gtk-toolkit. The best one imho

**transmission** - had qt and gtk-backend. Very simple but not bad too.

**ktorrent** - on Qt. Best one for KDE.

**qbittorent** - on Qt too, but w/o KDE dependencies.